# Beginner OOP; More methods vs Classes

Tags: python, class, oop, python-2.7

I'm learning Python and trying to get into classes. I'm trying to scrape some sites that often have different strings I use to identify the info I need. The challenge is that I get into situations where I could be looking for one of dozens of possible strings. At that point do I keep nesting if statements or create new classes, etc.

For example: In the Class below, I'm looking for the strings x, y or z in the html I return. If I find X I need to execute a function. Is it most effective to build that function out underneath that if statement or can I create a new function and call it within this class(ie. I create a new function called `x_Found()`) that gets parses the data I need.

```
class Link:
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.url = url
        x = 'abc'
        y = 'zyx'
        z = '123'

    def get_html(self):
        import urllib2
        html = urllib2.urlopen(self.url()).read()
        return html

    def find_text(self):
        html = self.get_html()

        if x in html:
            run a function called x_found()
        elif y in html:
            run a different function called y_found()
        elif z in html:
            run an even different function called z_found()
```

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries of Lambdas and/or method pointers.

```
method_map = {'x' : self.x_found, 'y': self.y_found, 'z':self.z_found}
strings_to_search = ['x', 'y', 'z']
for string in strings_to_search:
    if string in html:
        method_map[string]()
```

Comment: How would I incorporate x/y/z_found() into the class? Do I just create more methods below and it can call them? Do they have to be above?

Comment: As long as they are in the same class block, they can be above or below

Comment: Just a small note, I would initialize that dictionary outside the `for` loop so it doesn't get initialized on every loop.

Comment: Yeah, that's a good idea. Just wanted to show the syntax, i'll fix that.

Comment: I added a new function to the class and am calling it within another method and I'm getting the error "global name 'xyz' is not defined" - http://paste.ee/p/V2fja

Comment: Your `xyz` method is over indented that's why you can't call it from `get_html`

Comment: My apologies, if they are in the same class, you need the `self.`, i have corrected this in my answer.

Comment: bvidal - good catch. In the real code it's indented properly and still getting the same error

Answer (score 1):

In this instance you should not be using if statements at all. It would be far better style to create a dictionary which maps strings to functions and then calls the appropriate function within it.

Try something like this:

```
def string1_found():
    print "Found a string 1"

foo = {}
foo['string1'] = string1_found
```

Then you can just call one by

```
myfunc = foo['string1']
myfunc()
```

Comment: Down-voter, please explain the issue, though this answer is short I thought is provided a solution.

Comment: There is no such thing as `Dictionary()` and `foo['string1'] = string1_found()` will not allow you to call `foo['string1']()` later

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Thank you, I was just being lazy so I appreciate the kicking to encourage me to actually look at my reference book. Is it ok now or have I still left an issue?

Comment: I would just use `foo = {}` you need to store `foo['string1'] = string1_found` then you call it later using `myfunc = foo['string1'] myfunc()`, try it yourself  `i = int, then i("5")`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham You are completely correct. I just tried it in the interpreter. Ok, have actually run the code now so it definitely works. Thanks for the encouragement there.